# How can I use `schema` in apollo client cache?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I use `apollo-client` in a react project to manage UI state. I define a schema type for apollo mutation but it doesn't seem to work.

Below is how I create `apollo client` instance.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

export const createClient = () => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    resolvers: {
      Mutation: {
        ...alertResolvers
      },
    },
    typeDefs: [alertTypeDefs]
  });
};
```

Below code is the type schema definition. As you can see I have created a `showErrorAlert` return type of `Alert`.

```
export const alertTypeDefs = gql`
  type Alert {
    id: ID!
    message: String!
    type: String!
    duration: Int!
  }
  extend type Mutation {
    showErrorAlert(message: String!): Alert
  }
`;
```

I use below code to send mutation. As you can see that it doesn't return the `duration` in the return object. But the application works without any error. It seems that the type doesn't have impact on the application.

```
gql`
  mutation showErrorAlert($message: String!) {
    showErrorAlert(message: $message)  @client {
      id
      message
      type
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/#client-side-schema):

> You can optionally set a client-side schema to be used with Apollo Client, through either the  ApolloClient constructor typeDefs parameter, or the local state API setTypeDefs method... **This schema is not used for validation like it is on the server because the graphql-js modules for schema validation would dramatically increase your bundle size. Instead, your client-side schema is used for introspection in Apollo Client Devtools, where you can explore your schema in GraphiQL.**

In other words, the only point of providing `typeDefs` for local state is enable querying local state through GraphiQL in Apollo Client Devtools.

There is no type validation for local state, although the client will throw if there is a mismatch in the general shape of the object in the cache compared to what's being requested.

Comment: And how are you supposed to query a JSON object stored in your Apollo local cache? Assuming there are some unknown properties inside that object.